# Does iOS automation JavaScript support the substring function?

Tags: javascript, ios, ios-ui-automation

Just wanted to know: does iOS UI Automation JavaScript support the `substring` method? If yes, please provide a suitable example because I'm getting an error response for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use : substr()

```
  var str="Hello world!";
  var n=str.substr(2,3)
```

The result of n will be:

llo

It works. Tested.

P.S.Please accept anwser it if it works for you.

Comment: real problem is 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841946/javascript-to-parse-string-with-function'. See if you can help me on this :-|

Comment: @MANN: after going through above link , i think the approach is right. coincidentally I also did something like this for one of the UI automation project but stored function names in array. But there was no need of printing the function name so I haven't bothered about that.

Comment: thanks for the response. I just want to print a log where my queue is able to tell me which function it ran and how many times (say I want to store function name & count in some Array Map)!