# Javascript to parse string with 'function'

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have following string which needs to be parsed using JS.

```
function () {\n     MyClass.prototype.doSomethingFunction();\n       5-6 lines of coding\n  }
```

I tried parsing it, trimming whitespaces and newlines but nothing worked for me. Please let me know how can I get function name (doSomethingFunction) from the above string.

How I'm getting this string:

I have a queue where my functions are stored. Later in time my code picks a function from this queue (some logic here) and execute them. It works perfectly ok for me. But I just want to print the name of the function out of it! It's like '(classOBJ.myFunctionsQueue[n])()' is used to execute a function which is stored at nth location in myFunctionsQueue array. Make sense or I'm doing something wrong in here?

Thanks
MANN

Comment: Why do you need to parse JavaScript within JavaScript?

Comment: Are you mean to get a name of function who has no name?

Comment: Can you not populate your queue with the function name as well as a separate property? i.e., `["doSomethingFunction", "function () {\n... "]`.

Comment: MyClass.prototype.doSomethingFunction() is the whole namespace. I just want doSomethingFunction() out of it. Does this make sense?

Comment: Your solution sounds very fragile.  What is the bigger picture goal you are aiming for, perhaps there is a better approach overall?

Comment: I have a queue where my functions are stored. Later in time my code picks a function from this queue (some logic here) and execute them. It works perfectly ok for me. But I just want to print the name out of it! It's like '(classOBJ.myFunctionsQueue[n])()' is used to execute a function which is stored at nth location in myFunctionsQueue array. Make sense or I'm doing something wrong in here?

Comment: What is that code that invokes functions on a prototype, instead of calling them on an instance?

Comment: Can't reveal that much... sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a reg expression matching like this

```
var str = "function() {\n MyClass.prototype.doSomethingFunction();\n 5 - 6 lines of coding\n}";

var matches = str.match(/prototype\.(.+?)\(\)/);
if(matches){
    alert(matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: gr8... thats the thing I was looking for. Thanks a lot Diode. BTW using array to store your function is a good design or bad? From the comments above it sounds like I'm doing something evil!!!

Comment: @MANN: An array seems to be reasonable for a queue, but storing your functions as strings *is* evil.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you're executing functions stored as strings, you're probably doing it wrong (using `eval` or `new Function(body)`). Couldn't you use an object as the queue, with the function names as keys, and function references (not strings) as values? Like this:

```
var queue = {
    "funcName" : function() { /* do something */ },
    "otherFunc" : function() { /* do something else */ }
    /* etc. */
};
```

Then you can print all names an execute all function from a loop, for example:

```
for(var key in queue) {
    console.log(key); // function name
    queue[key]();     // execute function
}
```

Comment: I doubt that I'm storing my functions as string. Let me tell you what I'm doing : var myObj = new MYClass();
var queueOBJ = new QUEUECLASS(few param); queueOBJ.addTest(myObj.doSomethingFunction);   Is this design alright or ...

Comment: That looks fine. You said it was a string and needed parsing, hence my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the right approach for your application, but the current problem could be solved by something like

```
myFunctionString.split("\n").reduce(function(map, line) {
    if (/^\s*[^\s[\]]+\(\);?\s*$/.test(line))
        map.push(line.split(".").pop().replace(/\(\);?\s*$/, ""));
    return map;
}, []);
// returns an array of invoked method names
```

Comment: what I'm doing : var myObj = new MYClass(); var queueOBJ = new QUEUECLASS(few param); queueOBJ.addTest(myObj.doSomethingFunction); Is this design alright or ... even @bfavaretto thinks its alright. Would you mind telling me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You can't really rely on some code in a string, it might too easily change to something non-parsable. Also I don't understand your use case entirely, why would you want to get the property name of the first method called inside some function string?